# mpl-token-metadata library not installing build Failed

Tags: anchor, spl-token, rust, mpl-token-metadata

I tried different versions, after adding `mpl-token-metadata` library and then simply running `anchor build` fails with the following error.

```
use spl_token::state::is_initialized_account;
   | no `is_initialized_account` in `state`
```

[image]

Comment: you need to import spl_token as it seams like you are using it in your code

Comment: Don't know what was wrong but I solved the issue by creating a new anchor-lang project and copying the code files there. It worked. Thanks for the help buddy.

Comment: spl_token lib is included in anchor-spl so we don't need to worry about that.